# Querying specific devices on network

Tags: networking, command-line, terminal

I want identify specific devices on my network.

I am on MacOS. I used the command `arp -a`  to list the devices in my local network. Now I am presented with a list of devices, but there isn't much information here. How can I query each device, either in bulk or one at a time, for more detailed information such as what their name is, what sort of device they are, etc.?

Comment: there likely isn't a single built-in utility that would do it. I usually use nmap (on linux), so that might work for you, since I'm sure there has to be a mac version. That said software recommendations are off topic on this site, so I recommend rescoping your question to simply ask how, with less emphasis on an "application/utility".

Comment: thx @FrankThomas for the suggestion, yeah I'll rephrase my question

Answer (score 0):

nmap ("Network MAPper") may be the OG for this sort of advanced network device scanning and device querying. Here's the link to their MacOS platform binaries: https://nmap.org/download#macosx

nmap can scan ranges or individual network devices/addresses with a variety of scans in order to reveal detailed information about the devices. It does require there be at least some ports open on the devices. If the device has no ports open at all it may be able to tell the device is there, but not much else. But for most devices nmap can make a pretty educated guess, and I believe it even rates its percentage confidence in each identification. Over the years I've used it I've found it to be right far more often than not, but sometimes it gets an identification wrong, so being able to see the confidence level is handy.

While nmap itself is a cli utility, they publish a GUI, called Zenmap, which may be easier to use for those less comfortable with the CLI.

nmap has a variety of scanning arguments to meet your various needs. A sample scan may use these arguments:

- `-A`, to enable OS and version detection, script scanning, and traceroute;
- `-T4` for faster execution
- and then the hostname

This sample scan may produce output like this, depending on the features of the host you're scanning:

```
# nmap -A -T4 scanme.nmap.org

Nmap scan report for scanme.nmap.org (74.207.244.221)
Host is up (0.029s latency).
rDNS record for 74.207.244.221: li86-221.members.linode.com
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE     VERSION
22/tcp   open     ssh         OpenSSH 5.3p1 Debian 3ubuntu7 (protocol 2.0)
| ssh-hostkey: 1024 8d:60:f1:7c:ca:b7:3d:0a:d6:67:54:9d:69:d9:b9:dd (DSA)
|_2048 79:f8:09:ac:d4:e2:32:42:10:49:d3:bd:20:82:85:ec (RSA)
80/tcp   open     http        Apache httpd 2.2.14 ((Ubuntu))
|_http-title: Go ahead and ScanMe!
646/tcp  filtered ldp
1720/tcp filtered H.323/Q.931
9929/tcp open     nping-echo  Nping echo
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 2.6.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6.39
OS details: Linux 2.6.39
Network Distance: 11 hops
Service Info: OS: Linux; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:kernel

TRACEROUTE (using port 53/tcp)
HOP RTT      ADDRESS
[Cut first 10 hops for brevity]
11  17.65 ms li86-221.members.linode.com (74.207.244.221)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 14.40 seconds
```

Note, the above came from the beginning of [nmap's documentation page](https://nmap.org/book/man.html).

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old but I was looking for the same information, so I thought I'd share what I use.

My tool of choice isn't open source or free but I really like [iNet Network Scanner](https://inetapp.de/en/inetx.html) for MacOS. It provides me with an information about the devices on my network and I highly recommend it.

That being said, the reason for my search is that I'm looking to see if I could find more information about two devices that are on my network. Figured there must be a terminal method that might provide more detail.